# Compare dataframes and retrieve matching records

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Please suggest solution other than spark sql.

I have 2 tables in delta lake as below. Now, I need to check whether emp2.emp_no present in emp1.emp_id. So, I need to check whether 'df5' present in 'df3' dataframe or not.

If 'df5' data is present in 'df3', then retrieve those matching records from 'df5'. Can you help me on this please?

**Table Name: emp1**

| emp_id | dept_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 10 |
| 5 | 20 |

**Table Name: emp2**

| emp_no |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 20 |
| 25 |
| 3 |
| 2 |

sample code

```
--emp1 table
val data = Seq((1,10),(2,10),(3,20),(4,30),(5,20))
val df1=data.toDF("emp_id","deptno")
df1.show(false)
df1.write.format("delta").save("c:\\hi\\delta-table")
val df2=spark.read.format("delta").load("c:\\hi\\delta-table")
df2.show(false)
val df3=df2.agg(sort_array(collect_set("emp_id")).as("empids"))
df3.show(false)

--emp2 table
val data2 = Seq(2,20,3,4,10)
val df4=data2.toDF("emp_no")
df4.show(false)
df4.write.format("delta").save("c:\\hi\\delta-table2")
val df5=spark.read.format("delta").load("c:\\hi\\delta-table2")
df5.show(false)
```

I tried to compare like below. But, getting below error

```
val df6=df5.withColumn("chk",array_contains(df3.col("empids"),df5.col("emp_no")))
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) empids#1563 missing from emp_no#1932 in operator !Project [emp_no#1932, array_contains(empids#1563, emp_no#1932) AS chk#1958].;;
!Project [emp_no#1932, array_contains(empids#1563, emp_no#1932) AS chk#1958]
+- Relation[emp_no#1932] parquet

  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.failAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:43)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.failAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:369)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1.apply(CheckAnalysis.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.foreachUp(TreeNode.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$class.checkAnalysis(CheckAnalysis.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.checkAnalysis(Analyzer.scala:95)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1.apply(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:201)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:57)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:55)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:47)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$withPlan(Dataset.scala:3412)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.select(Dataset.scala:1340)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withColumns(Dataset.scala:2258)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withColumn(Dataset.scala:2225)
  ... 53 elided
```

Comment: Look into various `join` operations available in Spark. One of them will help you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

No need to collect all values of `emp_id` in an array and try to filter `df5` according to those values.

You can start from `df2` dataframe, extract distinct `emp_id`s from it and put them in a new `df3` dataframe, then join your `df5` dataframe with your new `df3` dataframe using inner join:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val df3 = df2.select(col("emp_id").as("emp_no")).distinct

val df6 = df5.join(df3, Seq("emp_no"))
```

> Note: if you want to keep same logic than in your sample code, you need to collect ids from `df2` before trying to compare them with ids in `df5`. However, you should ensure that number of distinct ids in `df2` is small so it can be collected:
>
> ```scala
> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
>
> val empids = df2.select("emp_id").distinct.collect.map(_.getInt(0))
>
> val df6 = df5.filter(col("emp_no").isin(empids: _*))
> ```